# I need to determine the High Card between two cards that are in string format IE D-A

Tags: java, compare, distributed

So it's my first time coding in Java Eclipse Mars and we have an activity that I'm stuck on. The activity is to simulate a card game with Two Players. Lets call them P1 and P2. The requirements are 
first: Is to create a deck of 52 cards, 
second: create a method to shuffle said deck, 
third: Is to distribute the cards to P1 and P2 alternately unti both have 26 cards on their own pile. 
fourth: Is that P1 and P2 draws a card from their respective piles then compare their cards to each other to see who has the higher card.
fifth: is that the winner takes both cards and puts it into their own pile. Game is finished when a player runs out of cards from their deck.

The part that I'm at done right now is up to the third. All I need now is to know how to assign a value to these cards so that the comparison part will be done with.

Ill only be putting necessary codes. Since my coding is way too messy.

```
String[] CurrentDeck = new String[52];
// This array contains the deck of cards to be distributed to each player
// This contains elements in this format:: "D-A", "D-K", "D-Q", "D-J", "D-10", "D-9", "D-8", "D-7", "D-6", "D-5", "D-4", "D-3", "D-2",... and so on.

String[] Pile1 = new String[52];
String[] Pile2 = new String[52];
// These represent the pile of cards for Player 1 and 2 respectively.
// They both start with 26 cards each.
// The reason they are 52 in size is because their pile can have 52 cards in it since
```

// winning gets you both cards that were compared in a round.

I have already distributed the cards to both piles correctly with
Pile1[0] and Pile2[0] are both top cards of their respective piles.

Now its time for both players to draw their top cards and compare it.
That is now the problem. I don't know how to put value into the cards for them to compare. And how to get the card from the loser of the round and put both cards in the deck of the winner.

And by the way, this is how the game works.
The comparison takes place first for the ranks of the card IE, 2-10, A, K, Q, J
S-5 beats D-3 since 5 > 3
The second comparison occurs when cards have the same rank. We now go to compare the suit of the cards IE Diamond, Heart, Spade, Club.
D-5 beats S-5 since D > S

So there it is thanks in advance for whoever can give me any ideas :)

Comment: Personally I'd make a class for each card, so you could represent them as an object, and make an array of them. Then you can write values for each card, and just compare the integer value of the cards, and have them also have names if you need to print it.

Comment: I guess you could contrive use of a `HashMap` here, but why would you need to? What are you mapping from and to? What are your keys, what are your values?

Comment: @RileyCarney do you mean a class for each card, or just a class for card, and create 52 instances? 52 classes seems like overkill.

Comment: Agree with @RileyCarney: Don't store Cards as Strings. Java is an Object Oriented language, so use it and create objects, i.e. create a single `Card` class with two fields: `suit` (D, H, S, C) and `rank` (2-10,J,Q,K,A, or use 2-14 internally). Then create 52 distinct instances of this class. Another good solution is for `suit` and `rank` to be enums.

Comment: @Andy Turner May seem like overkill, but when I created a card game it was extremely useful for comparing cards. You can 'hide' data in the card objects, and in my circumstance it made the code look much neater! I don't think it takes up that much memory as well, as you are often initializing objects (like Strings).

Comment: @RileyCarney but 52 classes? `class JackOfHearts {}`, `class QueenOfSpades {}`, `class FourOfClubs {}`...

Comment: @Andy Turner - Sorry, I see my grammatical error. I meant one class representing a card, then making 52 card objects.

Answer (score 0):

While it isn't my first recommendation, I wrote some code below that will work in your case. This will return an integer value for the card, and you can just check if the integer value is higher or lower.

```
public static int checkValue(String card)
{        
    String[] name = card.split("-");

    switch(name[1])
    {
        case "J":
        return 11;
        case "Q":
        return 12;
        case "K":
        return 13;
        case "A:
        return 1;
        default:
        return Integer.parseInt(name[1]);
    }
}
```

Personally I would create a whole new class for the card, but if you are just starting in Java, it may get a little confusing, as I'm guessing you're just used to working with one class.

For "*And how to get the card from the loser of the round and put both cards in the deck of the winner*" You can do something like...

```
String winCardsP1 = "", winCardsP2 = "";
// ...

// When a player wins
winCardsP1 += Pile2[i] + " ";
// OR
winCardsP2 += Pile1[i] + " ";
// ...

// Then to create the final array...
Pile1 = winCardsP1.split(" ");
Pile2 = winCardsP2.split(" ");

// This will make a new array with all the cards they won. 
// You will have to adjust your loop in order to compensate 
// looping through the decks each time, and when they have no cards they lose.

// The '...' stands for code in between the assignments.
```